# Failed to open an old iOS project which use AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdLde.png)

I always get these bugs when I open an old project or download a project from the Internet.
Why these bugs get out? And how to fix them?

Comment: i suggest you should remove it, then use cocoapod to pull AFNetworking to your project.

Comment: Install AFNetworking  through cocoa pod

Comment: use latest version downloading 2.4+ versions or at least 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why? The guy who added AFNetworking to this project placed this framework outside of project folder (hence the `../../../`). It's safe to assume he didn't ship the project together with it, so you have this build error.

How to fix? The easy way is to download AFNetworking and manually include its code in the project yourself. But you should use CocoaPods for those dependencies, like many suggested.

Answer (score 1):

please mention your xcode version and AFNetworking version.
If you are using cocoapod, please do pod update. hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

That project is just expecting AFNetworking in a certain location. Either put AFNetwoking in that location, or remove the reference from the project and re-add it, perhaps through CocoaPods.